# Using the While loop

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

6.) Scenario – You are playing a guessing game with your little cousin.  She wants you to guess her favorite color.  Create a program using the While loop. Below is a code I'm writing  but having  trouble with the while loop.

```
package loopscenario;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author macbook
 */
public class LoopScenario6 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 String blue = null;
 String yellow = null ;
 String red = null;
 String pink = "pink";
 String favoriteColor = null;

 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 Random randomNumber = new Random();
 Random aRan = new Random();


 while (!favoriteColor.equalsIgnoreCase(pink))

     if (favoriteColor.equalsIgnoreCase(blue))
     {
         System.out.println("Wrong color. Please try again.");
     }
     else if( favoriteColor.equalsIgnoreCase(yellow))
     {
       System.out.println("Wrong color. Please try again.");  
     }
     else if ( favoriteColor.equalsIgnoreCase(red))
     {
      System.out.println("Wrong color. Please try again.");     
     }
    else 
     {
      System.out.println("Yes!");     
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific trouble are you having with the while loop, and where? Editing your question to add this would improve the question and make it more answerable.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at loopscenario.LoopScenario6.main(LoopScenario6.java:27                        This is line 27 while (!favoriteColor.equalsIgnoreCase(pink))

Comment: Also, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: `String favoriteColor = null;` well crap, you never change this.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the future, if you don't understand the error messages, search Google or this site for them as they've usually been asked about here **many** times.